# Register Jackson MixIn in JavaEE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, jackson, jax-rs, mixins

On the basis of [this setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698350/use-jackson-as-jaxb-json-processor-in-javaee-application) (using Jackson as JAXB-provider in a JavaEE application): **How can I register my [MixIn modules](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)?**

In my client application using the JAX-RS client feature it is registered automatically. I've seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299944/jackson-mixinannotation-using-simplemodule-does-not-work), but where do I get the ObjectMapper from? I've tried to create on in my `ServletContextListener` and register the module there. But of course the mapper instance will be disposed after the `contextInitialized` method ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ContextResolver` as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29527901/2587435). With the `@Provider` annotation, the `ContextResolver` should be picked up from the scanning (assuming you are using kind of scanning; package scanning or classpath scanning)

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper.registerModule(new MixinModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return defaultMapper;
    }  
}
```

What happens, is that the `MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWrite` provided by your Jackson JAX-RS provider, will call the `getContext` method, to get the `ObjectMapper`